# How to recognize character from the image using java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-manipulation, barcode

I want to recognize the barcode from the image file using Java, but I am a beginner to development. So I do not have any idea on this. Please help me.

Comment: From your comments it seems you would like someone to come to your house and code it for you.  That will not happen.  Unless you can ask more specific 'questions' than "how to get bar from barcode image file" - I doubt you will solve this.  Perhaps you should hire someone that **isn't** a 'beginner to development'.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ has a very nice api for scanning barcodes in various formats

if you are interested in decoding a barcode yourself, have a look at this processing example
i have written a while ago
http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2009/09/22/barcodescanner-in-pure-processing

Comment: zxing library is not suitable for my appilication.we are doing vehicle identification number concept.which is not yet used in zxing library.

Comment: You mentioned several times that you want to be able to scan barcodes - what does that have to do with your vehicle identification? This answer is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The following links may help you. Check them out.

- [BarCode of image taken in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339867/barcode-reading-using-picture-taken-using-mobile-phone-camera)
- [Barcode image generator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java)

**EDIT after 1st comment:**

To get barcode from file, check the following link:

- [Java Barcode API](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-barcode-api?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29)
- [Java Barcode generator](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/java_barcode/)

Answer (score 1):

Asprise commercial library is the best solution

You have other alternate which can be useful

http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/